# Facebook user url system

Tags: php, facebook

In my project every user have his own page. But i wanna assign url to theese pages like in facebook: facebook.com/username. How does facebook's profile url system work? How to create pages for user like in Facebook (domain.com/username)? Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to search after mod_rewrite it allows to rewrite URLS to another url like the facebook one.

More information on the apache site:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I know about mod_rewrite. I mean, in facebook, index page simply gets username variable and changes whole page from db or there's another file hidden with modrewrite that processes usernames?

Comment: Yes there is probably another file that executes the code based on the username (or there own pages).

Comment: after it receives the username it does a select based on this username and then gets all of the information.

Comment: I wonder why facebook's other modules (facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xy) works simply like standart pages but index page works different. I thinks index page processes username and show whole content based on username. I'd want to discuss about it with someone.

Comment: there are other possibilities like if the file ends with an extension use that or else try to load a username. Or just a big array with all the pages that need to be accessable.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `.htaccess` file with `mod_rewrite` rules ([tutorial](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)) that pushes those requests to a .php file. There you can look at the original request, and fetch the user details.

Comment: I know about mod_rewrite. I mean, in facebook, index page simply gets username variable and changes whole page from db or there's another file hidden with modrewrite that processes usernames?